# Touch event offset relative to target element

Tags: javascript, touch, offset

I am using hammer.js for handling my touch events. I am performing a zoom on a canvas element. With the touch event I can only get the offset of my touch event relative to the page and not to the canvas element. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working this way:

```
hammertime_zoomer.on("transform", function(evt) {               
    var c = dojo.position(evt.target);
    var c1 = c.x;
    var c2 = c.y;

    var p1 = evt.gesture.center.pageX;
    var p2 = evt.gesture.center.pageY;

    var x = p1 - c1;
    var y = p2 - c2;

    vp.zoomIt(x, y, evt.gesture.scale);
});
```